# c# getting invalid cast exception while copying excel cell value to datarow

Tags: c#, excel, interop

c# getting invalid cast exception while copying excel cell value to datarow

I am trying below code

```
int noofrow = 1;

for (int r = noofrow; r <= rows; r++)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    for (int c = 1; c <= cols; c++)
    {
        if (((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)objSHT.Cells[r, c]).Value2 != null)
        {
            //string s11 = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)objSHT.Cells[r, c]).Value2;
            dr[c - 1] = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)objSHT.Cells[r, c]).Value2;
        }
        else
        {
            dr[c - 1] = "";
        }
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    dt.AcceptChanges();
}
```

Comment: Does this `dr[c - 1] = objSHT.Cells[r, c].Value2;` not work?

Comment: @shahkalpesh No it is not working

Comment: What does `objSHT.Cells[r, c].Value2` return? If not `Value2`, does `Value` work?

Comment: @shahkalpesh for both I am getting same error... Also I am using Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: How can there be InvalidCastException when you read `objSHT.Cells[r, c].Value2`? Also, remove the cast from this line `(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)objSHT.Cells[r, c]).Value2 != null` too.

Comment: @shahkalpesh I did check as you mentioned.... but no luck.. I am getting same error.
Also one more thing I need to add In VS 2019 there is Microsoft Excel 15 object Library is there.